# How to fix that jump to previous activity about startActivityForResult and onActivityResult?

Tags: android, android-intent

I developed three activities which are called as Activity A, Activity B and Activity C. Firstly, Activity A is my main activity and When application is launched , Activity A is created. After that I am moving to Activity B with `startActivity(this,ActivityB.class)` , there is no problem up to here.The problem is When I want to move from Activity B to Activity C and I want to fetch data from Activity C , however sometimes I can fetch it and sometimes I cannot fetch it and moving to Activity A.I will put my code pieces about problem , How can I be sure about that I can fetch data all the time ?

> Moving from Activiy A to Activity B.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
        intent.putExtra(User.USER_ID,id);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
```

> Moving from Activity B to Activity C

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,ActivityC.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

> Moving from Activity C to Activity B with data.

```
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putByteArray("data",data);
    returnIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    finish();
```

> In Activity B , I handle coming data into

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        try {
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            byte[] photo = bundle.getByteArray("data");
            setPhoto(photo);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine.However sometimes after finish Activity C, application jump to directly Activity A and I want to sure that application has to pass from Activity C to Activity B.

**About Activity B lifecycle :** Firstly, everything okey activity climb to onResume() , when startActivityForResult is called , it stays onto onPause() . After coming back from Activity C sometimes ,I said, It works fine as Activity B againg climb to onResume() ,However sometimes there no any lifecycle log message and directly pass to Activity A without any destroyed onto Activity B.

Comment: You do not need Intent returnIntent = new Intent(this,ActivityB.class); Intent returnIntent  = new Intent() is enough...

Comment: @ruan65 thanks comment,however problem still occurs.

Comment: I can assume that your setPhoto() method throws an exception (sometimes if photo too big or ...whatever) that have been handled to close B, so A goes in front...

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are trying to get the data from activity C into activity B.
If that is so, then

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

must be defined in B.
The data returned using  `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);` from C
will be available in the `onActivityResult(...)` of B. NOT C.
For your question as to why you are jumping directly from C to A, make sure you're not calling `finish()` in the `onActivityResult(..)` of B.

Comment: Sorry about that , I edited question, of course I defined it into B .